# Is there a shorter way of declaring CodingKeys?

Tags: swift

Say you have a `struct` for a model of your API response. Let's say it has 50 members. However, 5-7 members are non-standard casing, you could have `AUsernAme` or `_BTmember`, but the rest are all snake case `credit_score` or `status_code`.

Rather than writing all members like this:

```swift
struct MyStruct {
  let aUserName: String
  // +50 more...

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case aUserName = "AUsernAme"
    // +50 more...
  }
}
```

Is there a way that we can write it like this?

```swift
struct MyStruct {
  @CodingKey("AUsernAme") let aUserName: String
  let creditScore: Int
  // +50 more ...
}
```

**Edit:** I guess this is not possible with the current Swift version, but does anyone know if this would somehow be included in the future versions of Swift?

Comment: Apple knows that writing CodingKeys is tedious, and they will do something about when they can.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which Sweeper provided is a great solution to your problem, but IMO it may display great complexity to your problem and to the next developers who will read this code.

If I were you, I would just stick to writing all the CodingKeys for simplicity. If your worry is writing a lot of lines of cases, you can write all the cases that doesn't need custom keys in one line and just add the keys with unusual/non-standard casing on new lines:

```swift
case property1, property2, property3, property4, property5...
case property50 = "_property50"
```

And since you mentioned that the rest are in snake case, not sure if you know yet, but we have `JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy.convertFromSnakeCase`.

Hope this helps `tol! :)

Comment: Even better, https://app.quicktype.io will write it in this style for you automatically. (You of course should also consider whether a type with 50 properties should be rethought to break it up into smaller objects. Even if the JSON comes down that way, it doesn't mean you have to use it that way. But that's separate from this question.)

Comment: This is a cool tool @RobNapier! Didn't know this! Have to bookmark this now. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Rhenz I don't mind writing all the cases, I can just do a multi cursor copy paste. I'm just thinking about the possibility of using property wrappers, like how we can just do `@JSONProperty("somePropName")` in Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a custom `keyDecodingStrategy` just before you decode instead?

```
struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey, Hashable {
    var stringValue: String

    init(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int?

    init(intValue: Int) {
        self.intValue = intValue
        self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
    }
}

let mapping = [
    "AUsernAme": "aUserName",
    // other mappings...
]

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({ codingPath in
    let key = codingPath[0].stringValue
    guard let mapped = mapping[key] else { return codingPath.last! }
    return AnyCodingKey(stringValue: mapped)
})
```

This assumes your JSON has a single level flat structure. You can make this into an extension:

```
extension JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
    static func mappingRootKeys(_ dict: [String: String]) -> JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
        return .custom { codingPath in
            let key = codingPath[0].stringValue
            guard let mapped = dict[key] else { return codingPath.last! }
            return AnyCodingKey(stringValue: mapped)
        }
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .mappingRootKeys(mapping)
```

If your JSON has more levels, you can change the type of the dictionary to `[JSONPath: String]`, where `JSONPath` is a type that you can create that represents a key in a nested JSON. Then add a bit of code that converts the coding path, which is just an array of coding keys, to `JSONPath`. This should not be hard to write on your own.

A simple way is to just use `[AnyCodingKey]` as `JSONPath`, but there are many other ways too, and I encourage you to experiment and find the one you like the best.

```
typealias JSONPath = [AnyCodingKey]

extension AnyCodingKey {
    init(codingKey: CodingKey) {
        if let int = codingKey.intValue {
            self.init(intValue: int)
        } else {
            self.init(stringValue: codingKey.stringValue)
        }
    }
}


extension JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
    static func mappingRootKeys(_ dict: [JSONPath: String]) -> JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
        return .custom { codingPath in
            guard let mapped = dict[codingPath.map(AnyCodingKey.init(codingKey:))] else { return codingPath.last! }
            return AnyCodingKey(stringValue: mapped)
        }
    }
}

let mapping = [
    [AnyCodingKey(stringValue: "AUsernAme")]: "aUserName"
]
```

---

It is not possible to use a property wrapper for this. Your property wrapper `@CodingKey("AUsernAme") let aUserName: String` will be compiled to something like this (as per [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#initialization-of-synthesized-storage-properties)):

```
private var _aUserName: CodingKey<String> = CodingKey("AUsernAme") 
var aUserName: String {
    get { _aUserName.wrappedValue }
    set { _aUserName.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

There are two main problems with this:

- Assuming you don't want to write `init(from:)` for all the 50+ properties in `MyStruct`, code will be synthesised to decode it, assigning to its `_aUserName` property. You only have control over the `init(from:)` initialiser of the `CodingKey` property wrapper, and you cannot do anything about how `MyStruct` is decoded in there. If `MyStruct` is contained in another struct:

  ```
    struct AnotherStruct: Decodable {
        let myStruct: MyStruct
    }
  ```

  Then you can indeed control the coding keys used to decode `myStruct` by marking it with a property wrapper. You can do whatever you want in the decoding process by implementing the property wrapper's `init(from:)`, which brings us to the second problem:
- The coding key you pass to the `CodingKey` property wrapper is passed via an initialiser of the form `init(_ key: String)`. But you control the decoding via the initialiser `init(from decoder: Decoder)` because that is what will be called when the struct is decoded. In other words, there is no way for you to send the key mappings to the property wrapper.

Comment: @MarkAnthonyDegamo if you want it to convert the keys from snake case as a default, you’ll probably have to some string manipulation in the `.custom` closure. Since you also have non-standard mappings, you can’t use the built in `.convertFromSnakeCase` decoding strategy.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Sweeper. I don't quite get it yet, but I'll try and experiment with the code you provided.